# Calling object (A) that holds another object (B) from from the object B

Tags: java, object

I have following simplified situation:

```
public class Owner {

   private int ownerId;
   private Telefon telefon;

}

public class Telefon {

   private int telefonType;



}
```

Now I want to get the owenerID, if I have any Telefon object. I don't want to store the ownerId in the Telefon object.

Any way to do this?

Comment: Make Telefon implement `equals()` and filter your Owner collection on the Telefon object.

Comment: The problem is, that there could be  3 Owner with a telefon from type 3. So thous objects could look identical and only differ in the owner that holds the telefon.

Comment: If 3 Owner has that specific Telefon object then the correct result are those 3 owners.

Comment: What is the relationship between **owner** and **telefon**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the Owner's telefon `owner.getTelefon()` is `equals` to your Telefon object. If so, you get the Owner's id `owner.getId()`.
Note - you have to implement the `equals()` method in the Telefon class in order to do it.

Comment: The problem is, that there could be 3 Owner with a telefon from type 3. So thous objects could look identical and only differ in the owner that holds the telefon. As I know,ownerA.getTelefon().equals(otherOwner.getTelefon()); would be true if thats the case?

Comment: Giving this specific information, I don't think you can gen only one result if there are 3 owners with the same telefon type. If you request the ownerId of the Owner that has a specific Telefon, you will get all the ownerIds of the Owners that has that specific Telefon.
If you want to return a single result, then each Owner must have a unique Telefon.

Comment: Based on your idea what if I implement:
```
public boolean check(Telefon telefon) {
   return this == telefon;
}
```
into Telefon. Since even if there are 2 telefons with the same type, they would point to different instances, when they are initialized in 2 different owners, so this method would return false?

Comment: Since you want to check if the Owner's telefon is equal to your Telefon object, you need to implement a `public boolean check(Telefon telefon) {
  return this.telefon == telefon;
 }`method  in your Owner class.

Comment: You can create a new Owner with an id and a telefon, and create another Telefon and use the check method in order to see if your Owner has that particular telefon.  `Telefon telefon = new Telefon(3);
  Owner owner = new Owner(1, telefon);
  owner.check(telefon);`